# Spotify automatic startup mystery

Tags: login, startup, spotify

Trying to get rid of Spotify's startup at login time I found an interesting behavior: while its plists are not present in any of the known locations such as Library/LaunchAgents and Library/LaunchDaemons and it's also not set to Open at Login either in the Dock or during logout, it still manages to start up somehow.

I've created a new test user, started the app just once, was greeted with a login prompt, closed the app and it decided it would start ever since. I've tried deleting the entire contents of the user's home folder in the Terminal while running as another user (rm -rf /users/testuser/*), but Spotify would start anyway.

Wonder how they do that? It's pretty easy to check by downloading and running the app, there's no need to even create an account.

The point of the question is to understand the mechanism rather than actually stop it from opening (there's a switch in the app).

Comment: One idea that crossed my mind just now is to run fs_usage|grep otify while using that switch, but I am not able to log in right now and cannot access that switch.

Comment: can you tell us what Mac and what OSX

Comment: OSX 10.11.6, Mac Pro early 2008

Answer (score 2):

A lot of functionality, like login items, extensions/kexts, LaunchAgents or other Helpers can be packed into the application bundle these days.

If you look closely at the content of the Spotify.app, by right- or control clicking it and selecting "Show Package Contents", you'll find a "Library" folder enclosed in the Content's folder.  Within it there is a LoginItems folder, containing the login item.
    /Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/StartUpHelper.app/Contents/MacOS/StartUpHelper

This "StartUpHelper" will launch Spotify at login.  This seems to be the application's default behaviour.

You wrote:

> Otherwise it would start for every new user added to the system.

I certainly have seen Spotify auto-launch on a user created after it had been installed, logging out of the user that created the new account and setting up the new user account from the login screen (alternatively two restarts were needed for Spotify to launch at login in the new user account).
 Only when Spotify got installed after the user was created, did it not launch at login.

**A test in an attempt to explain, why some users will not see the auto-launch of Spotify at login:**

I created and set up a new user before Spotify was installed on a different user account and, after Spotify was installed (again in a different user account), tried several logouts/logins and restarts to make sure it didn’t auto-launch at login for this new user.
 I also noted the user’s DARWIN USER DIRECTORY running the following command...
`getconf DARWIN_USER_DIR`

I also had a user for whom Spotify auto-launched at login every single time.  Again I noted the user’s DARWIN USER DIRECTORY.
Logged into this last mentioned user I quit Spotify and deleted...
`com.apple.LaunchServices-231-v2.csstore`
 ...from the Darwin User Directory.
 Then I copied the same file from the other user’s Darwin User Directory (for whom Spotify didn’t auto-launch at login) over to this user’s directory (in Finder, to make sure the file’s owner would also change).

Then I logged out and rebooted several times into the user, for whom Spotify did auto-launch, but the behaviour stopped and Spotify refrained from launching.

PS. For further in depth information on login items within an application bundle, I’d suggest signing up for a free Developer account and getting acquainted with (some of) the [documentation on application design](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLoginItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000172i-SW5-SW1) (you don't have to sign up though, just to read the documentation).

Comment: Sure, but however tightly you pack the bundle doesn't explain how the app should start up by itself. There has to be *something* starting it.

Comment: @ЗахарJoe I do not know what you mean by "however tightly you pack the bundle".  The preference you set in the app either starts it or doesn't.  The StartUpHelper then launches it.  Did you read the document I linked to at the Developer site?

Comment: Yes, I did read it. A part of it references opening applications as a part of doing some work, like when opening a document, and then there's a reference to Info.plist which supposedly controls a startup of a helper app - there're no strings they reference in Spotify helper app's Info.plist. Furthermore, I see nowhere how a plist placed systemwide on a helper app would "know" whether it should start for a particular user, and that's precisely what happens. Otherwise it would start for every new user added to the system.

Comment: I'm _guessing_ the app has to register itself with Launch Services first (i.e. launch at least once) and maybe get rid of the quarantine attribute, before it can exhibit its default behaviour of launching at login.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be listed in the user's Login Items in System Preferences?

Comment: No, there is no need with the LoginItems built into the application bundle itself, although it would be more transparent (and convenient) for the user in System Preferences.

Comment: All right. I'm looking for an answer that points me to a file that tells Spotify which user chose to auto-start the app and which didn't (its location in the file system) and the explanation of that autostart method here, probably with a reference to a specific point in the documentation literature that ties it all together.

Comment: In support of what I said: go to your $TMPDIR and remove your Launch Services database in your test volume (**not** production volume): `open $TMPDIR/../0`.  There, (logged into a user, where Spotify auto-launches at login) I deleted `com.apple.LaunchServices-231-v2.csstore` (I'm guessing 231 relates to that user 501, since there should be more csstore files, which I deleted all, but only this one returned after logging back in and re-testing).  I also deleted the Spotify user files in that user's Library: in Application Support, Caches and Preferences.  Spotify did not launch at login.

Comment: Launch Services: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html

Comment: As an aside: since deleting the file mentioned in my comment above, gets rebuilt for the next startup, a more permanent and the proper way is to de-register Spotify from Launch Services: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/Spotify.app` (which doesn't show you the file(s) in the file system though)

Comment: There is no com.apple.LaunchServices* file anywhere in my file system. I don't think LaunchServices does what you think it does. Even in the documentation you linked there's no mention of auto-starting an app. Just launching, but in a different context. Here's an article that explains it in a more human-readable form: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/11/launch-services-database-problems-correcting-and-rebuilding/ To summarize, you can register your helper app to open another app, but it doesn't explain how the helper app starts up automatically in the first place.

Comment: De-registering an app with LaunchServices is for all intents and purposes the equivalent of deleting said app from /Applications.

Comment: "There is no com.apple.LaunchServices* file anywhere in my file system." What do you get for `ls -al $TMPDIR/../0 | grep com.apple.LaunchServices` ?

Comment: "...it doesn't explain how the helper app starts up automatically in the first place."  It’s in "LoginItems".  If you want to know how "LoginItems" work in detail, be it in System Preferences, or within the application, I don’t know. Some API or other.  I’m neither coding for Apple, nor am I a developer to name APIs, frameworks and what not (though the relevant framework - Service Management Framework - was mentioned in the link I’d posted in my answer).

Comment: "De-registering an app with LaunchServices is for all intents and purposes the equivalent of deleting said app from /Applications." It explains your question of why Spotify didn’t launch for other users that hadn’t launched it yet, but did auto-launch after it had been opened once.  I don’t know what else there is to be said to make it any clearer.

Comment: With any luck someone else might come along with an answer you can accept (or at least believe;).

Comment: @3axap Joe I’ve updated my answer with a test, you may be willing to accept to explain the login behaviour for different users?

Comment: TIL. Great answer mate.